# How do I insert a bash variable containing a string with forward slashes into a jq command

Tags: bash, jq

Im trying to insert a string ("/rest/config/hostgroup/${HGID}") into a json file using jq within a bash script.

initially it threw:

jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '/' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at , line 1:

So I set the string to be a jq variable like this:

echo $HOSTJSON | jq --arg HGP "$HGPATH" .hostgroup.ref=[$HGP] > host1.json

This didn't error but does not insert anything into the json other than [] as though the HGP variable isnt being populated.  Omitting the square brackets around HGP throws the below indicating an empty variable:

jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at , line 1:
.hostgroup.ref=
jq: 1 compile error

I've tried this on the CLI and get the same results, can confirm HGPATH is populated:

```
echo $HGPATH
/rest/config/hostgroup/5
cat host.json | jq --arg HGP "$HGPATH" .hostgroup.ref=$HGP
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.hostgroup.ref=              
jq: 1 compile error
```

$HGID is being pulled from a query earllier in the script and is just a number and $HOSTJSON is a large JSON string

```
HGPATH="/rest/config/hostgroup/${HGID}"
echo $HOSTJSON | jq --arg HGP "$HGPATH" .hostgroup.ref=[$HGP] > host1.json
```

Comment: You need to (single-)quote your jq command, otherwise `.hostgroup.ref=$HGP` is expanded to `.hostgroup.ref=` by bash

Comment: @Aaron that worked thanks post it as the answer!?

echo $HOSTJSON | jq --arg HGP "$HGPATH" '.hostgroup.ref=[$HGP]' > host1.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before being executed, your `jq --arg HGP "$HGPATH" .hostgroup.ref=$HGP` command is first expanded by `bash`. It's useful for the `"$HGPATH"` part where you want `jq` to run with the value of the variable, but it's problematic for the `.hostgroup.ref=$HGP`, where bash doesn't have knowledge of any `HGP` variable and will replace `$HGP` by the empty string, resulting in the following command being executed :

```
jq --arg HGP /rest/config/hostgroup/5 .hostgroup.ref=
```

That explains the error message you're getting : `jq` complains it has unexpectedly reached the end of the command when parsing `.hostgroup.ref=`, which indeed isn't a correct `jq` command.

To avoid this, you will want to quote the `jq` command in single-quotes (which you should always do), telling `bash` to avoid expanding the command :

```
cat host.json | jq --arg HGP "$HGPATH" '.hostgroup.ref=$HGP'
```

As a side note, `jq` accepts an additional input file parameter, so you can write your pipeline as a single command :

```
jq --arg HGP "$HGPATH" '.hostgroup.ref=$HGP' host.json
```